# Multiple events under one button android

Tags: java, android, events, button

I have the following code which creates an event when a button is clicked. I would like to know how to create more than one, (Say 5) events by pressing this button. Thank you for any help!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
// button.setOnClickListener(this);
final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);


final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) {


         if (checkBox.isChecked()) {

             { 

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy, h:mmaa"); 
            long lnsTime = 0, lneTime = 0;

                    Date dateObject;

                    try{
                    String dob_var = "August 16, 2012, 11:35PM";

                    dateObject = formatter.parse(dob_var);

                    lnsTime = dateObject.getTime();
                    Log.e(null, Long.toString(lnsTime));

                    dob_var = "August 16, 2012, 11:59PM";      

                    dateObject = formatter.parse(dob_var);

                    lneTime = dateObject.getTime();
                    Log.e(null, Long.toString(lneTime));
                    }

                    catch (java.text.ParseException e) 
                        {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.i("E11111111111", e.toString());
                        }

                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);

                     intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                  intent.putExtra("title", "9:00AM Start");
                  intent.putExtra("description", "There will be a 9:00AM start tomorrow.");
                  intent.putExtra("eventLocation", "Chris' house");
                  intent.putExtra("beginTime", lnsTime);
                  intent.putExtra("endTime", lneTime);
                  startActivity(intent);

             }



    }
```

The code creates the single event just fine so far, its just I need multiple to be created, preferably without the "save/cancel" screen.

Comment: By event you mean launching a new activity? Judging from your code, it seems so. Please do clarify.

Comment: Do you want 5 different tasks to be done by clicking a single button?

Comment: Yes, basically I want it to create 5 events. The code I showed only created 1.  (They would be different dates)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve doing multiple tasks on click of the same button by using conditions in your `onClick` method of the `onClickListener`. Just like you did in your code by checking if `checkbox isChecked()`, similarly you can add more events by implementing the following suggestions:-

1. if `checkbox2 isChecked()`
2. if `checkbox` and `checkbox2` both are satisfying `isChecked()` condition,
3. one more condition you can simply specify when none of these above is met, i.e., the `else` condition.

Well, by using the above mentioned code in your `onClick` you can specify four events on the same button click. Hope this helps..

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. And the checkbox2 is for a completely different function.